# Why fraction (with power) in fraction doesn't work?

Tags: fractions

```
$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}{x^{10}}$$
```

here is my code. It said,

```
Emergency stop.
<*> Worksheet2_main

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on ./Worksheet2_main.log.
***------------------------------------------------------------
*** Running bibtex on Worksheet2_main ...
***------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I tried to write the numerator by its own.

```
$$e^{-\frac{1}{x}$$
```

It just works. How could this happen?

Comment: (1)welcome, (2) as always on this site please post a full minimal example instead of sniplets. (3) count your `}`'s, the first argument for `\frac` is not properly closed, you only closed the `e^`

Comment: You showed only the final part of the error message, but not the initial part, which reported that "File ended while scanning use of \frac." That should be a pretty good tip-off as to where the problem occurs.

Comment: Tbh, it is so hard to check all of these curly brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is issued because the numerator part of the fractional expression isn't terminated with a `}` (closing curly brace).

You should also contemplate inline-fraction notation, `{-1/x}`, for the exponent of `e`. The resulting expression will be both more compact and easier to read as the terms are typeset in script style rather than in scriptscript style.

Finally, note that using `$$` to start and end display-math mode is deprecated in LaTeX; use `\[` and `\]` instead. For more information on this subject, see [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
\[
\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{x^{10}} =
\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{e^{-1/x}}{x^{10}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have been careful to that. That link is helpful. I appreciate it.

Comment: @YuchenZhang or if using `amsmath` try `\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}`, this makes it easy to change it to a numbered equation (remove the `*`'s) if needed. Some editors have a nice interface for changing environments.